# What are the steps to convert a large class from static to non-static?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static

I have a rather large open source class that I need to convert from static to non-static.

The reason I need to do this is to make it thread safe; I want one copy of the class per thread.

In general, what are the recommended steps to convert a C# library from static to non-static?

Comment: Hmm, too general of a question. Post some code, you'd get better answers.

Comment: This is _waaaaaay_ too broad to be effectively answered. Forgetting for a moment some of the general constructs to be applied, or removed (which I'll presume, for the sake of argument, that you already know), everything else is purely circumstantial to your scenario (or a set of such). i.e. You'll need more than just a way of making the class non-static, you'll need to be damn sure it _is_ thread safe: that is not just a consequence of an instance class.

Comment: Find "static" replace with ""

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - Perhaps you didn't notice the **Tounge in Cheek** formatting I used on that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have upgraded Data Layer from static to no static class. So

1st : remove "static" keyword on class and method

2nd : Add in your old static class a Singleton as well

```
public class Foo 
{

    #region Singleton

    Foo()
    {
    }

    public static Foo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        static Nested() { }

        internal static readonly Foo instance = new Foo();
    }

    #endregion
```

3rd : Replace in each call for your class by Foo.Instance.DoSomething() instead Foo.DoSomething()

4th : Compile and profit

Answer (score 2):

To make it compile? Removing `static` from all the members should do it.

If you want something more kosher, then you should take common parameters from all the calls and move them into the constructor.

Seems pretty simple to me. Do you have a specific issue with that?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is that as this is such a large class it's not easy to visualise how to do it in one go, so you wanted some steps to follow. Here goes:

1. Convert to Singleton
2. You'll need to correct the places that reference the static class, by replacing each term
   `MyClass` with the singleton getter `MyClass.instance()`. Keep a list of all those places so that you can revisit them easily.
3. On all those places that you found, figure out how best to dependency-inject the `MyClass.instance()` rather than refer to it globally using the `MyClass`.
4. Un-singleton-ize your class to a canonical one. The DI work you have done should make it easy to swap from the singleton getter to a normal constructor.
5. Now start using more than one instance at a time and bug-fix advanced concurrency problems that result from that.

Run your test framework between each step.